Ошибка в терминале при компиляции .cpp vscode
При запуске любого cpp файла в vscode на этапе билда активного файла g++.exe в терминале появляется ошибка, но, код запускается и работает корректно.
Ошибка:
Выполнение задачи: c:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -std=c++17 -g D:\need\test\main.cpp -o ${fileDirname\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe
    строка:1 знак:86
    + ... .exe -std=c++17 -g D:\need\test\main.cpp -o ${fileDirname\${fileBasen ...      
    +                                                                 ~ Используйте в именах переменных "`{", а не "{".
        + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OpenBraceNeedsToBeBackTickedInVariableName

Мои конфигурационные файлы:
launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        },
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++.exe сборка и отладка активного файла",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Включить автоматическое форматирование для gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Задать для варианта приложения дизассемблирования значение Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe сборка активного файла"
        }
    ]
}

tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "c:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "c:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe сборка активного файла",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Задача создана отладчиком.",
            "presentation": {
            "clear": true
      }
        }
    ]
}

settings.json:
{
    "files.associations": {
        "ostream": "cpp",
        "iostream": "cpp",
        "iomanip": "cpp",
        "chrono": "cpp",
        "iosfwd": "cpp",
        "thread": "cpp",
        "array": "cpp",
        "string_view": "cpp",
        "initializer_list": "cpp",
        "utility": "cpp",
        "valarray": "cpp",
        "optional": "cpp",
        "sstream": "cpp"
    }
}

c_cpp_properties.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**", 
                "c:/msys64/mingw64/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "8.1",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}


как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

я уже читал, знаю

скобки не хватает: "${fileDirname\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe" -> "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"

спасибо! теперь ошибки нету
